# cannot create virtual device on android studio on windows 7

Tags: android, android-studio, android-virtual-device

When I create a new virtual device on android studio it says : 
event log is

```
IOException : makeRelative: incompatible drive letters
running error PANIC: Could not open AVD config file: C:\Users\3mr\.android\avd\Nexus_5_API_21.avd\config.ini
```

What is the cause of this?

Answer (score 1):

This is bug https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=81023 and seems to be caused by having Android Studio installed on a different drive letter than the SDK. A workaround until the bug is fixed would be to install them on the same drive letter.

In the comments you say that both Android Studio and the SDK are installed on D:, so I think the problem in your case is that your home directory is on C:. As a workaround until the bug is fixed, you can try installing everything on C:.

Comment: more explain please i am new in android development

Comment: You most likely have Android Studio installed on C: and the SDK installed on D:, or some such. Install them both on the same drive letter.

Comment: Android Studio installed on  d:   and the SDK installed on D:,

Comment: Hmm, well then the problem seems to be that your home directory is on C:. If everything else is installed on C: it will probably work.

Comment: if i try to do new virtual device automatic make folder on C: called (.android)

Answer (score 0):

I just want to add a comment to Scott's answer, but I don't have the reputation for it so I'll pretend this is an answer.

According to the issue linked to in Scott's answer, Google has fixed this in the code.  I don't know when it will show up in an AS release, but I'll bet it shows up in the dev channel pretty soon.

Answer (score 0):

The bug is now fixed update to Android Studio 1.0.1

Comment: You don't have enough rep to comment yet but just for reference this answer would typically be better as a comment.